# Dúvida em consulta SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Estou pensando em fazer uma View para o desenvolvimento de relatórios, e esbarrei no seguinte problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de juntar as colunas PUBLICO1, PUBLICO2, PUBLICO3, PUBLICO4 em uma unica coluna.

Ex.: AM0173 teria 2 linhas

ID_3_ETAPA    |    PUBLICO 
AM0173               |             2    
AM0173               |            1

Consigo fazer isso em um select?

Comment: Desse modo a coluna publico ficou null em todas as linhas.

Comment: transforme seu comentário em uma resposta, assim poderá ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui usando UNPIVOT

```
SELECT ID_3_ETAPA
     , PUBLICO 
  FROM MINHA_TABELA UNPIVOT ( PUBLICO FOR PUBLICO_COR IN ( PUBLICO1 AS '1'
                                                         , PUBLICO2 AS '2'
                                                         , PUBLICO3 AS '3'
                                                         , PUBLICO4 AS '4'))
```